# converting 256*2048 cell to 256*256 cell where each element is 1*8 char in matlab

Tags: matlab

```
P=8;
l=8*ones(2048/8,1);
M=1;
m=M*ones(256/1,1);
Chaos_bin=mat2cell(C_abs,m',l');
%C_abs is 256*2048 cell of binary bits
%size(Chaos_bin)
for i=1:256
  for j=1:256
    D{i,j,1}=num2str(Chaos_bin{i,j});
    %class(D{i,j,1})
    size(D{i,j,1})
   end
end
```

I tried this way but size(D{i,j,1}) is returning 1*22 char.Can anyone help why this is happening.Acording to me it should be 1*8

Comment: If `C_abs` is really a cell of size `256*2048`, then the size of `D{i,j,1}` is equal to the size of `Chaos_bin{i,j}` transformed to string. This means that if the resulting size is `[1 22]`, then `Chaos_bin{i,j}` is not a binary, but a number with 22 digits. Are you positive that your `Chaos_bin` cell contains what you think it contains? And then there are other problems, but this should be addressed first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the extra blank spaces which appear between your bits. For instance:

```
>> Chaos_bin{1,1}

ans =

1     1     1     0     0     1     1     1

>> num2str(Chaos_bin{1,1})

ans =

1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1

So you need to remove extra blank spaces between the bits using:

>> DD = num2str(Chaos_bin{1,1});
>> Blank = isspace(DD);
>> DD(Blank)=[];
>> DD

DD =

11100111
```

In addition I think that your `C_abs` is not a cell but a numeric ordinary matrix.

You may need a code like this:

```
P=8;
l=8*ones(2048/8,1);
M=1;
m=M*ones(256/1,1);
C_abs=round(rand(256,2048));
Chaos_bin=mat2cell(C_abs,m',l');
clear D
for i=1:256
    for j=1:256
        TMP=num2str(Chaos_bin{i,j});
        BLANK=isspace(TMP);
        TMP(BLANK)=[];
        D{i,j,1}=TMP;
    end
end
```

Comment: Please use *one*  answer, thus edit your previous one instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Removing blank space worked in my case. C_abs is cell only i generated using cross chaotic map.